# CakePHP 2.5.5 updating associated has_many and belongst_to models

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I have a view/vendor/add.ctp with fields from two associated tables:Vendors and Addresses.I'm able to save normally data in both tables at same time, but if I try to update a record, it creates a new row in the database instead of update it.

I'm searching on cakephp documentation and on google for hours! but can`t find anything that help me.

Association on Vendor Model:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Address' => array(
        'className' => 'Address',
        'foreignKey' => 'vendor_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

Association on Address Model:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Vendor' => array(
        'className' => 'Vendor',
        'foreignKey' => 'vendor_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

Here is my VendorsController "edit" action

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Vendor->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid vendor'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {

        if ($this->Vendor->saveAssociated($this->request->data)) {  
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The vendor has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The vendor could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {
        $options = array('conditions' => array('Vendor.' . $this->Vendor->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->request->data = $this->Vendor->find('first', $options);
    }
    $categories = $this->Vendor->Category->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('categories'));
}
```

Please, I need help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `Vendor` model is not receiving the `id` of the row to be saved, and so it is creating a new one when you save your data.

You need to change this line:

```
        ...
        if ($this->Vendor->saveAssociated($this->request->data)) {  
        ...
```

to this:

```
        ...
        $this->Vendor->id = $id;
        if ($this->Vendor->saveAssociated($this->request->data)) {  
        ...
```